# Slight confusion of `this` in a JavaScript call back function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this, anonymous-function

```
$.ajax({url: path_to_file, cache: false, success: function(html_result){
    $("#window_" + this.id + "_cont_buffer").html(html_result);})
```

Now then. This function call is with in a function of a class. `this.id` is a property of said class. will this pass the function value of this.id into the string the anonymous function, or will it try to evaluate it when the function actually gets called, thus making no sense.

If this is not going to work how I want it to, can you recommend how I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the particular case of `$.ajax()`, `this` can be specified using the `context` attribute.  So, Matthew's solution gives you the `this` that is specified in the function that you make the `$.ajax` function call from.

You can see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information on setting the `this` for the `success` callback.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice that he added `context:this`. So that is basically forcing the `this` in the call back function to be be the `this` that is my instance making the AJAX request. clever stuff this.

Answer (score 1):

By default `this` will be an internal jQuery object.  However, you can override that by explicitly specifying `context: this` as part of the call.  Then, `this` will be the object you're calling it from.

```
$.ajax({url: path_to_file, context: this, cache: false, success: function(html_result){
    $("#window_" + this.id + "_cont_buffer").html(html_result);})
```

will do what you want.

Comment: @thecoshman, if you don't use the `context: this`, `this` will be an internal jQuery object.